# Code completion for external libraries for Spacemacs

Tags: intellij-idea, emacs, clojure, clojurescript, spacemacs

In IntelliJ with Cursive plugin we have [code completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/basic-code-completion-completing-names-and-keywords.html), which

> helps you complete the names of classes, methods, fields, and keywords within the visibility scope. When you invoke code completion, IntelliJ IDEA analyses the context and suggests the choices that are reachable from the current position of the caret.

When a project is indexed this also finds methods in imported libraries:

[image: Working]

Here we pop up all methods available in `reagent.core` after I type `reagent/`.

I want to have the same behaviour in Spacemacs with Clojure mode. What I get is only the already defined names in the same file:

[image: Spacemacs does not show all possibilities]

What I tried is generating a TAGS file with `ctags` by pressing `<SPC> p G`. But this seems not equivalent of IntelliJ's indexing since it shows other completions, like so:

[image]

Is it possible to display the completions from imported libraries in Spacemacs Clojure in the same way as IntelliJ Cursive can? And if so, how?

Comment: Try to start CLJS REPL for your project and require your edited namespace in REPL. Then try if it auto-completes correctly.

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl It turned out I needed to make sure that 1) I used the ClojureScript Cider jack-in and 2) I required the libraries in my REPL (by evaluating `(require 'reagent.core)`. This can probably be optimized, but at least I have the completion I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clojure support in Spacemacs is configured by adding the clojure layer.

Edit ./spacemacs and add clojure to the list of layers defined in `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers function

Restarting Emacs will download by the related packages for Clojure.

Comment: Thanks, but I have done this already. Still there is no auto-completion for imported libraries.

Comment: It does seem to work for some packages though. For `clojure.test` it works as I expect! See http://i.imgur.com/ncgJ8ag.jpg. Maybe something was wrong with the way I was importing the `matrix` and `reagent` packages? Shouldn't it display the available methods in those too? Your answer suggests auto-completion for imported libraries should be available out of the box.

Comment: As explained in the comment below the question it works by using the correct Cider jack-in (ClojureScript in this case) and loading the namespaces into the REPL.